# Why can explicit instantiation of a function template not use inline or constexpr

Tags: c++, templates, inline, constexpr, explicit-instantiation

Referring to [cppreference's section on function templates](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function_template):

> Explicit instantiation of a function template or of a member function
>   of a class template cannot use inline or constexpr

These topics, `inline` and `constexpr`, seem separate and unrelated. Why does this restriction exist?

Comment: Because both `inline` and `constexpr` can lead to there not being an actual *instance* of the function? Which of course goes against the whole "explicit *instantiation*" part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because they serve opposite purposes.

The point of explicit instantiation is, in a *source* file, to provide definitions for templates that your project needs so that you don't have to fully define the template in your [header file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/495021/2069064).

The point of `inline` is to allow function definitions in a *header* - so that multiple definitions of the function across multiple translation units can be collapsed into one.

`constexpr` functions must have definitions visible for the compiler to actually be able to invoke them at compile-time. There is no link-time `constexpr`.

It doesn't make sense to explicitly instantiate an `inline` or `constexpr` function - those function templates must already be defined in header files and so will be able to be implicitly instantiation on-demand.

Comment: It just occurred to me that some users may also use explicit instantiations as a way to restrict the set of valid instantiations. That is something you might also want to do with `inline` or `constexpr` templates, but explicit instantiations have no effect on program semantics there.